# Matching query doesn't exist Error while searching

Tags: django, search, django-templates

I am trying to make a search field and whenever I search for anything this error arise `User_Model matching query does not exist.`
*User_Model is a table

views.py

```
def searchForMembers(request):
    ser = request.GET['member']
    allMembers = User.objects.filter(username=ser)
    return render(request, 'memberMembersPage.html', {'memberList': allMembers})
```

html page

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="get" action="{%url 'searchForMembers'%}">
  {%csrf_token%}
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a member" name="member">
  </div>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
path('search/', views.searchForMembers, name='searchForMembers')
```

Comment: Can you please share the *full* traceback?

Comment: yes, I edited it @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @willem asked for error traceback. Can you add please?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this 
How can I add it ? @ShafikurRahman

Comment: You click the [edit] button, and add extra content.

Comment: I mean how can I get the error traceback ?
it only appears in the cmd like this :User_Model matching query does not exist. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: got it http://dpaste.com/3X4BMY3 @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Here your traceback suggests that the error is in a (`User.objects.get(..)` request, whereas your view has a `.filter(..)`). It is correct that a `.get()` can raise such error, since it is possible that for a given username, no corresponding `User` exists.